# What is the direct sum of an index family of Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am trying to understand this definition on Wikipedia:

[image]

So the direct sum for finitely many Hilbert spaces makes sense, but I don't understand what exactly is the direct sum of an infinite family of Hilbert spaces. So what does an element in this object look like? And it looks like the infinite sum of norms needs to be finite, so how can we sum an uncountably infinite sequence?

Comment: You have an index set that is potentially uncountable. However, for every element in the direct sum, there appear at most countably infinite many nonzero terms (otherwise the series simply does not converge).

Comment: You can imagine this as a kind of buffet of your favourite foods. You want to be able to choose from all of your beloved dishes, but that does not mean you want to combine them all at once :)

Comment: @SeverinSchraven thank you, that makes a lot more sense

Comment: Right... an uncountable sum of positive real numbers cannot converge. This is an important/standard/not-toooo-hard exercise. So, yes, in Hilbert spaces with large (uncountable...) Hilbert bases, for any particular vector only countably-many coefficients can be non-zero...

Comment: For uncountable index sets which are still measure spaces, the appropriate generalization is the **direct integral**, not the direct sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that summing an “uncountable sequence” of nonnegative reals only makes sense when the sequence has all but countable many elements zero.

For suppose $I$ is uncountable, and we have some function $f : I \to (0, \infty)$. Then we can show there exists some $n \in \mathbb{N}_+$ such that $f^{-1}((1/n, \infty))$ is uncountable.

For if all $f^{-1}((1/n, \infty))$ were countable, we would have $I = f^{-1}((0, \infty)) = f^{-1}(\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^\infty (1/n, \infty)) = \bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^\infty f^{-1}((1/n, \infty))$ which is the countable union of countable sets, hence countable. But we know $I$ is uncountable.

So there is some $n > 0$ such that $f^{-1}((1/n, \infty))$ is uncountable, hence infinite. So we would have $\sum\limits_{i \in I} f(i) = \infty$ by any reasonable definition.